# Number sequence puzzle stuck on

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Stuck on this number sequence puzzle for a while now, today was talking about IQ tests with somebody so thought I'd ask here.

> 1, 2, 33, ?, 555, 23, ?, 222

The source is INRC 2018 Q3 (btw if anyone wants to I still have 14 questions there I still couldn't figure out, including this one, happy to work on it together).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think:

> $1,2,33,22,555,23,7777,222$.

Because:

> Factor the number if it is not prime, else if it is the $n^{th}$ prime, write it $n$ times.